# How do I write a custom init for a UIView subclass in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, instantiation

Say I want to `init` a `UIView` subclass with a `String` and an `Int`.

How would I do this in Swift if I'm just subclassing `UIView`? If I just make a custom `init()` function but the parameters are a String and an Int, it tells me that "super.init() isn't called before returning from initializer".

And if I call `super.init()` I'm told I must use a designated initializer. What should I be using there? The frame version? The coder version? Both? Why?

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The `init(frame:)` version is the default initializer. You must call it only after initializing your instance variables. If this view is being reconstituted from a Nib then your custom initializer will not be called, and instead the `init?(coder:)` version will be called. Since Swift now requires an implementation of the required `init?(coder:)`, I have updated the example below and changed the `let` variable declarations to `var` and optional. In this case, you would initialize them in `awakeFromNib()` or at some later time.

```
class TestView : UIView {
    var s: String?
    var i: Int?
    init(s: String, i: Int) {
        self.s = s
        self.i = i
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Then by all means make them `var`. But the default best practice in Swift is to declare variables `let` unless there is a reason to declare them `var`. There was no such reason to do so in my code example above, hence `let`.

Comment: `super.init()` must be called before initializing self params?

Comment: @LightNight I made `s` and `i` Optional to keep things simple here. If they were not optional, they would also need to be initialized in the required initializer. Making them optional means they get to be `nil` when `super.init()` is called. If they weren't optional, they would indeed need to be assigned before calling super.init().

Answer (score 55):

I create a common init for the designated and required. For convenience inits I delegate to `init(frame:)` with frame of zero.

Having zero frame is not a problem because typically the view is inside a ViewController's view; your custom view will get a good, safe chance to layout its subviews when its superview calls `layoutSubviews()` or `updateConstraints()`. These two functions are called by the system recursively throughout the view hierarchy. You can use either `updateContstraints()` or `layoutSubviews()`. `updateContstraints()` is called first, then `layoutSubviews()`. In `updateConstraints()` make sure to call super **last**. In `layoutSubviews()`, call super **first**.

Here's what I do:

```
@IBDesignable
class MyView: UIView {

      convenience init(args: Whatever) {
          self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
          //assign custom vars
      }

      override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           commonInit()
      }

      required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
           commonInit()
      }

      override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
           super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
           commonInit()
      }

      private func commonInit() {
           //custom initialization
      }

      override func updateConstraints() {
           //set subview constraints here
           super.updateConstraints()
      }

      override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           //manually set subview frames here
      }

}
```

Comment: But what if you want to initialise some properties in `commonInit` method, but you can't place it after `super` in this case because you should initialise all properties BEFORE `super` call. Lol it seems like dead loop.

Comment: This is how Swift initialization often works: search for "two-phase initialization". You can use implicitly unwrapped optionals, but I recommend against it. Your architecture, especially when dealing with views, should initialize all local properties. I've used this commonInit() method to hundreds of views now. It works

Answer (score 33):

### Swift 5 Solution

You can try out this implementation for running Swift 5 on XCode 11

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    var customParam: customType
    
    var container = UIView()
    
    required init(customParamArg: customType) {
        self.customParam = customParamArg
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        // Setting up the view can be done here
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    

    func setupView() {
        // Can do the setup of the view, including adding subviews

        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        // setup custom constraints as you wish
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You can also add `private init() { fatalError() }` to make sure your custom init must be used

Comment: this will cause crash if uiview is place into storyboard, which called init with coder

Answer (score 19):

Here is how I do it on iOS 9 in Swift -

```
import UIKit

class CustomView : UIView {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);

        //for debug validation
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
        print("My Custom Init");

        return;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented"); }
}
```

Here is a full project with example:

- [UIView Example Project (with SubView example)](http://jaostech.com/ios/workByDay/16_10_01/0_0%20-%20UIView.zip)

Comment: There is no need for that `return` or the semicolons.

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I do a Subview on iOS in Swift -

```
class CustomSubview : UIView {

    init() {
        super.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);

        let windowHeight : CGFloat = 150;
        let windowWidth  : CGFloat = 360;

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        self.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/2, y: 375);

        //for debug validation
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();
        print("My Custom Init");

        return;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented"); }
}
```