# UIView initial method in swift always shows error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uikit, init

I have a custom view derived from `UIView`,in `init` method like this:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    if ([super init])
    {
        self.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
or self = [[UIView alloc]init];
    }    
    return self;
}
```

It never shows the error, but when I use Swift

```
init() {
    self.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
}
```

The compiler tells me:

> `Super.init` isn't called on all paths before returning from initialiser

then I add `super.init()` and the compiler tells me:

> Convenience initializer is declared here (`UIKit.UIView`)

How can I use some initial method like `self = [[UIView alloc]init];` in a Swift `init` method?

Comment: Why don't you do `super.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);` like there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339145/how-do-i-write-a-custom-init-for-a-uiview-subclass-in-swift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this...

```
init()
{
    super.init(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    // Other initialization operations...
}
```